# Powerline - No such file or directory /scripts/powerline-config

Tags: powerline

i am using ubuntu 18. I am trying to add powerline to my oh-my-zsh terminal.

I have installed powerline like so.

```
pip3 install powerline-status
```

Then i edit my ~/.zshrc file to include:

```
. /home/kay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh


 pip3 show powerline-status
Name: powerline-status
Version: 2.7
Summary: The ultimate statusline/prompt utility.
Home-page: https://github.com/powerline/powerline
Author: Kim Silkebaekken
Author-email: kim.silkebaekken+vim@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/kay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

When i restart the terminal i get the following error:

> /home/kay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh:210:
>   no such file or directory:
>   /home/kay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scripts/powerline-config

Comment: Ran into the same on Ubuntu 18.2. Eventually solved by installing the apt package rather than through pip: `sudo apt install powerline`. For zsh in your case, that gives you `/usr/share/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh`

Answer (score 9):

It works for me:

1. `mkdir $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scripts/` if not exists
2. Find where `powerline-config` locates. For example `$HOME/.local/bin/powerline-config`
3. `cp $HOME/.local/bin/powerline* $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scripts/.`